# Rails: request.referrer == request.url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, request, referrer

Perhaps I misunderstand how `request.referrer` works, but isn't it suppose to provide you with the url of the page the user is coming from? So for instance, if they're viewing an article and then click edit, their request might look like this:

```
request.referrer = http://localhost:3000/article/1
request.url = http://localhost:3000/article/1/edit
```

If that's the case, then I'm getting odd behaviour, because the user's `request.referrer` is always set to the current url. What might be causing this? It's worth noting that I'm using an AJAX powered site, and all these requests are remote.

Answer (score 0):

`request.referrer` should be the URL you are making the request from, if you are with AJAX I think you should change your URL for your referrer to change.

Comment: I'm using `pushState` to set the address bar URL and add entries to the history. Might that be affecting things?

Comment: are you changing URL with pushState to B and URL remains in A?

Comment: The opposite, actually. I change the URL with pushState, and it changes correctly. Unfortunately, the referrer changes with it.

Comment: I think that's the idea of referrer, to save the URL from which request is being made. Maybe I am not understanding something.

Comment: So the problem is that its not being saved as the URL from which the request is made, but as the URL the client is currently on. Both the referrer and the current URL end up the same. Perhaps I don't understand this correctly either, but I don't think that's how it's suppose to operate.

Comment: do you mean with current URL the requested URL?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant.